# Executing a for loop with gnu parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parallel-processing, scripting

I'd like to use gnu parallel to exec a function inside a bash script in a for loop and I'm not able to figure out how from the info I got online .
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_racks(){
query that outputs a list of racks 
}

get_hosts() {
query that outputs a list of hosts by rack(passed as param to the func)
}

get_gw() {
query that outputs a list of gateways
}

check_ping() {
HOSTS=(`get_hosts`)
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt $SIZE ] ; do
  ssh $HOSTS "ping -c 5 ${GATEWAYS[$COUNTER]} " ;
  COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1)) ;
done
}

RACKS=(`get_racks`)
HOSTS=(`get_hosts`)
GWS=(`get_gw`)
SIZE=${#GWS[@]}
COUNTER=0

for rack in ${RACKS[@]}; do
  parallel check_ping | tee output.txt 
done
```

I'd like to execute the for loops and what happens inside in parallel while controlling the number of concurrent jobs and output everything into a single file . The final file should have all the data the function returns and also print to stdout .
Also , the check_ping has a part of sshing to a remote machine and pinging a GW, this part happens actually in parallel with a custom ssh command we have that ssh to all the hosts in the array in parallel and pings a GW .

Thanks much

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
RUN_COMMANDS() {
...
}

export -f RUN_COMMANDS

parallel -j4 RUN_COMMANDS ::: “${FILES[@]}” | tee output.txt
```

You will want `parallel -k ...` if the order is important.

Comment: Oops, add a space here `RUN_COMMANDS() {`

Comment: Sorry this was a syntax error in my pseudo code , the actual code was fine. I still get this error

Comment: I presume you really are using `bash`?

Comment: If you are still getting errors, please click `edit` under your original question and paste in your actual code and the actual errors so folks can assist you further.

Comment: You need `export -f check_ping` somewhere a few lines before `parallel ...`

Comment: ... and you need `parallel check_ping ::: "${RACKS[@]"` like my example. And you need to remove the `for` loop, like my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159817/discussion-between-john-doe-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

get_racks(){
    # query that outputs a list of racks
    echo rack01
}
export -f get_racks

get_hosts() {
    # query that outputs a list of hosts by rack(passed as param to the func)
    echo host01
    echo host02
}
export -f get_hosts

get_gw() {
    # query that outputs a list of gateways
    echo gw1
    echo gw2
}
export -f get_gw

ping_gw() {
    rack="$1"
    get_hosts "$rack" | parallel -S - --onall ping -c 5 ::: "`get_gw`"
}
export -f ping_gw
get_racks | parallel ping_gw && echo All hosts and gws are up
```

If you have more functions/variables/aliases then consider using `env_parallel` instead. That way `env_parallel` will do the exporting for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer @OleTange , however I get `/bin/bash: ping gw : command not found` . I read in another thread that you said it could be due to a bug with the version of parallel ?

Comment: Are you copying the full text? I have just tested on all releases of GNU Parallel since 2014. They all work. It is unlikely to be a bug in GNU Parallel.

Comment: Yes, still returns command not found . I'm running it as a regular user account.

Comment: Most likely something is messed up in your environment. See if you can reproduce the error on any of these:      http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualboximage/files/

Answer (score 0):

Parallel can be used in a very similar way to xargs, it even has the params of xargs implemented.

```
#!/bin/bash

RUN_COMMANDS(){
    ...... 
}

FILES=(file1 file2 file3)

echo ${FILES[@]} | parallel RUN_COMMANDS | tee output.txt
```